# Apex TOP 20 Accounts grouped by text field

Tags: apex, soql, group-by

I would need support with my Apex Code.
I want to get the TOP 20 Accounts ordered by a Number field "Total Quantity" grouped by a text field "Country". 
I need to get all the IDs of those accounts. For example, I need to display the TOP 20 Accounts for the following Country : Germany, Spain, Portugal. 
Is there a way to do that by a SQOL query? If not, how can I do that with Apex code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a SOQL to achieve your **goal1**, i.e. Top20 accounts GROUPED BY Country and Aggregated by TotalQuantity. However, you won't be able to get their IDs, as there could be multiple accounts under each country. For that purpose, you will be required to write some code. That should also not be so difficult either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with SOQL. SOQL supports only sorting and aggregation.

You can theoretically SORT by Country and Total Quantity, but you'll need some code to separate them anyway